# Why some hardcoded values in testing affects others?

Tags: java, android, junit, mocking

I'm trying to figure out how to write Unit Tests and I stuck at one point:

Suppose we have two tests (view and service are mocked):

```
@Test
public void shouldStartMainActivityWhenUsernameAndPassowordAreCorrect() throws Exception{
    when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn("james");
    when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond"); //bond
    when(serivce.login("james", "bnd")).thenReturn(true);  //bnd gives error

    presenter.onLoginClicked();

    verify(view).startMainActivity();

}

@Test
public void shouldShowErrorMessangeWhenUsernameAndPasswordAreIncorrect() throws Exception{
    when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn("james");
    when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond"); // bond
    when(serivce.login("james", "bnd")).thenReturn(false); // bnd gives no error

    presenter.onLoginClicked();

    verify(view).showCredentialsError();
}
```

This is my presenters method:

```
public void onLoginClicked() {
    String username = view.getUsername();
    if (username.isEmpty()){
        view.showUsernameError(R.string.username_error);
        return;
    }
    String password = view.getPassword();
    if (password.isEmpty()){
        view.showPasswordError(R.string.password_error);
    }
    boolean loginSucceeded = service.login(username, password);
    if (loginSucceeded){
        view.startMainActivity();
    }else{
        view.showCredentialsError();
    }

}
```

How comes that "bnd" hardcoded value is compared with "bond" hardcoded value from the very another method?

For example:

```
when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond"); //bond
when(serivce.login("james", "bnd")).thenReturn(true); //bnd
```

this give me an error, while changing it to

```
when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond"); //bond
when(serivce.login("james", "bond")).thenReturn(true); //bond
```

gives no error.

Comment: As I explained in the below answer, you are getting the error in first case  because you have defined the mock of `Service` for only `{"james","bnd"}` and your program is trying to invoke `login` method on `service` with different parameters i.e. `{"james","bond"}`. Since, there is no such mock you end up getting a `Null Pointer Exception`. If you don't want to worry about the parameters passed and want your mocks to work for any set of Strings then start using Matchers such as `anyString()`. For Example, `when(serivce.login(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have mocked the two scenarios when your service returns a boolean saying if the login is successful or not.

**You have following mocks:**

1. Mock for `view.getUsername()` which returns `james`. Whenever this method is invoked on your test class from your unit test then it will return this value.
2. Mock for `view.getPassword()` which returns `bond`. Whenever this method is invoked on your test class from your unit test then it will return this value.
3. Mock for `serivce.login()` which takes 2 arguments i.e. `{"username","password"}` and returns you the login status i.e. `true` or `false`. Whenever this method is invoked on your test class from your unit test with same set of parameters then it will return these value.

In the first test case you are returning `false` from your mock for Username: `james` and Password: `bnd` and in the second test you are returning `true` for the same set of parameters.

> when(serivce.login("james", "bnd")).thenReturn(true);  //bnd gives
>   error

Here you are returning `true` for `{"james", "bnd"}`.

> when(serivce.login("james", "bnd")).thenReturn(false); // bnd gives no 
>   error

Here you are returning `false` for `{"james", "bnd"}`.

Right now this mock is not getting executed in either of the two cases. This is because `username` and `password` in the presenters class always takes the values from the first 2 mocks i.e. `view.getUsername()` and `view.getPassword()`. These mocks are returning `james` and `bonds` respectively in both the test cases.

Logically you should be returning `true` or `false` from the test cases if and only if the arguments are `{"james","bonds"}` and not anything else. This will then be validated with the parameters returned by the other 2 mocks and based on whether they exactly matches or not, this third mock will be executed and will return the boolean.

**Positive Scenario:**

```
when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn("james");
when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond");
when(serivce.login("james", "bond")).thenReturn(true); /* Corrected */
```

**Negative Scenario:**

```
when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn("james");
when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn("bond");
when(serivce.login("james", "bond")).thenReturn(false); /* Corrected */
```

Comment: @Ms Yvette Just a small doubt. With the current scenario, he'll get error in both the cases because the mock won't be there for `service.login()` and it will always return `null`.

Comment: @Ms Yvette I always face troubles with Android Studio. :D

Comment: >This is because username and password in the presenters class always takes the values from the first 2 mocks - this is the only thing I needed. But why?

Comment: Because when you are saying `when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn("james");` you are actually telling the `view` to return `james` when `getUsername()` method is invoked. And since your class is taking up the values from this method in `String username = view.getUsername();`, it always ends up initializing the `Username` string with `james`. Similar thing is happening for `Password` also and it is getting initialized by `bond`. This is the whole essence of mocking! :)